# How to search a string in the elasticsearch document(indexed) in golang?

Tags: search, indexing, go, elasticsearch

I am writing a function in golang to search for a string in elasticsearch documents which are indexed. I am using elasticsearch golang client [elastic](https://github.com/olivere/elastic). For example consider the object is tweet,

```
type Tweet struct {
    User    string
    Message string
    Retweets int
}
```

And the search function is

```
func SearchProject() error{
    // Search with a term query
    termQuery := elastic.NewTermQuery("user", "olivere")
    searchResult, err := client.Search().
        Index("twitter").   // search in index "twitter"
        Query(&termQuery).  // specify the query
        Sort("user", true). // sort by "user" field, ascending
        From(0).Size(10).   // take documents 0-9
        Pretty(true).       // pretty print request and response JSON
        Do()                // execute
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
        panic(err)
        return err
    }

    // searchResult is of type SearchResult and returns hits, suggestions,
    // and all kinds of other information from Elasticsearch.
    fmt.Printf("Query took %d milliseconds\n", searchResult.TookInMillis)

    // Each is a convenience function that iterates over hits in a search result.
    // It makes sure you don't need to check for nil values in the response.
    // However, it ignores errors in serialization. If you want full control
    // over iterating the hits, see below.
    var ttyp Tweet
    for _, item := range searchResult.Each(reflect.TypeOf(ttyp)) {
        t := item.(Tweet)
        fmt.Printf("Tweet by %s: %s\n", t.User, t.Message)
    }
    // TotalHits is another convenience function that works even when something goes wrong.
    fmt.Printf("Found a total of %d tweets\n", searchResult.TotalHits())

    // Here's how you iterate through results with full control over each step.
    if searchResult.Hits != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Found a total of %d tweets\n", searchResult.Hits.TotalHits)

        // Iterate through results
        for _, hit := range searchResult.Hits.Hits {
            // hit.Index contains the name of the index

            // Deserialize hit.Source into a Tweet (could also be just a map[string]interface{}).
            var t Tweet
            err := json.Unmarshal(*hit.Source, &t)
            if err != nil {
                // Deserialization failed
            }

            // Work with tweet
            fmt.Printf("Tweet by %s: %s\n", t.User, t.Message)
        }
    } else {
        // No hits
        fmt.Print("Found no tweets\n")
    }
    return nil
}
```

This search is printing tweets by the user 'olivere'.  But if I give 'olive' then search is not working. How do I search for a string which is part of User/Message/Retweets?

And the Indexing function looks like this,

```
func IndexProject(p *objects.ElasticProject) error {
// Index a tweet (using JSON serialization)
    tweet1 := `{"user" : "olivere", "message" : "It's a Raggy Waltz"}`
    put1, err := client.Index().
        Index("twitter").
        Type("tweet").
        Id("1").
        BodyJson(tweet1).
        Do()
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
        panic(err)
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("Indexed tweet %s to index %s, type %s\n", put1.Id, put1.Index, put1.Type)

    return nil
}
```

**Output:**

```
Indexed tweet 1 to index twitter, type tweet
Got document 1 in version 1 from index twitter, type tweet
Query took 4 milliseconds
Tweet by olivere: It's a Raggy Waltz
Found a total of 1 tweets
Found a total of 1 tweets
Tweet by olivere: It's a Raggy Waltz
```

**Version**

```
Go 1.4.2
Elasticsearch-1.4.4
```

**Elasticsearch Go Library**

```
github.com/olivere/elastic
```

Could anyone help me on this.? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you search and find data depends on your analyser - from your code it's likely that the standard analyser is being used (i.e. you haven't specified an alternative in your mapping).

The [Standard Analyser](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) will only index complete words. So to match "olive" against "olivere" you could either:

1. Change the search process

e.g. switch from a term query to a [Prefix query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) or use a [Query String query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with a wildcard.

2. Change the index process

If you want to find strings within larger strings then look at using [nGrams](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) or [Edge nGrams](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) in your analyser.

Comment: I am new to elasticsearch. I appreciate the help.  Could you tell me how can I change the index process?. So that it will be helpful to search a string matching with all fields in the JSON.

Comment: The first step is set up an analyser and then reference it in your mapping. There's a good introduction here - http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

```
multiQuery := elastic.NewMultiMatchQuery(
    term,
    "name", "address", "location", "email", "phone_number", "place", "postcode",
).Type("phrase_prefix")
```